# UTF-16 XML to HTML in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, utf-16

I have a string stored in a SQL Server database table column that is currently a VarChar(Max) but the content is UTF-16 XML.  Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><Content><control name="txtGeneral" value="Hi Bryan,&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;This is a sample message stored in the database that I need to get out in HTML. I can&amp;amp;#39;t seem to figure out how to get it out into HTML. &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Thanks!&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Robot.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;-----Original Message-----&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Date:      08-21-15 19:57&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;From:     System Test, Microsoft Corp&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;To:         Framework.NET&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Subject:  RE: RE: RE: RE:  &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" /></Content>
```

The data, stored raw, is not XML/datatype but I can do the conversion in my select (see below). I am pulling it out via .NET/ADO so I have it locally in a string for display in HTML.  I just need to convert it for a textbox or HTML element so that it is displayed on the screen.

I can parse in t-sql the element (@value) I want but this does not do the encoding changes for me.  Here is my sample query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),m.Content)).value('(/Content/control/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM Messages m
WHERE MessageID = 85713;
```

I can use either .NET or t-sql for the conversion.  I will be selecting only a single message at a time so performance should not be an issue.

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
Hi Bryan,

This is a sample message stored in the database that I need to get out in HTML. I can&amp;amp;#39;t seem to figure out how to get it out into HTML. 

Thanks!

Robot.


-----Original Message-----

Date:      08-21-15 19:57

From:     System Test, Microsoft Corp

To:         Framework.NET

Subject:  RE: RE: RE: RE:
```

convert via: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Thanks!

Comment: The text has html special character so use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string); and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string);

Comment: The XML declaration is spurious but it seems you have found a way around it in your query. It should match (and the content should match, too) the column collation. The writer might run into problems (as replacement characters, dropped characters or exceptions) if the content being written contains characters that the column collation doesn't support. Perhaps a bug report is called for.

Answer (score 2):

There are many serious flaws:

- Do not store XML on string base, use the native XML type
- Do not handle XML as a string, use the native XML methods
- If - for any reason - you have to deal with it on string level use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`
- Never use 1-byte-encoded `VARCHAR(MAX)`. This will nead extra conversions and can lead to silly errors.
- Do not store the xml-declaration `<?xml blah ?>`. This is needed to specify a file's encoding. Within SQL-Server an XML is **always unicode / UCS 2**

If you can change the above, you should really consider to do this. If not, here's an approach:

First cast the `VARCHAR(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, then to XML. Together with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` the `UTF-16` will no longer disturb. Then use `.value()` to retrieve the value of the so named attribute.

```
DECLARE @mockMessages TABLE(Content VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockMessages VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><Content><control name="txtGeneral" value="Hi Bryan,&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;This is a sample message stored in the database that I need to get out in HTML. I can&amp;amp;#39;t seem to figure out how to get it out into HTML. &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Thanks!&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Robot.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;-----Original Message-----&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Date:      08-21-15 19:57&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;From:     System Test, Microsoft Corp&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;To:         Framework.NET&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Subject:  RE: RE: RE: RE:  &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" /></Content>');

SELECT CAST(CAST(m.Content AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).value(N'(/Content/control/@value)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
FROM @mockMessages AS m;
```

The same is - in principles - valid for `.Net`.

### UPDATE: Some words about encoding

SQL-Server does neither support UTF-8, nor *real* UTF-16. There is a 1-byte encoding, which is *extended ASCII* (codepage/character mapping) and a 2-byte encoding, which is unicode / UCS-2 (which is almost UTF-8, at least with 99% of the usually seen characters). If you need your output UTF-8 encoded you must do this in your application. In almost any case you consider SQL Server's XML output (in UCS-2) as UTF-16. The communication between SQL-Server and .Net-code is unicode by default

Comment: This is a vendor's system, I have no control over how the data is stored.  I just have read access into it and I need to display the results.  

Thanks for the response, I will review and try out your suggestion.

Comment: Recent versions of SQL Server support supplementary character-aware collations/functions (some with and some—newer ones—without the _SC suffix). In fact, [SQL Server provides data types such as nchar and nvarchar to store Unicode data. These data types encode text in a format called UTF-16.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Japanese_Collations)

Comment: @TomBlodget True... It's hard for me to consider the need for special collations as *native support* 